# Open browser not working in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, webstorm

I use WebStorm 10.0.4 on Windows 7.

I have a single page Angular application that I am working on in WebStorm. Up to this point I have always been able to preview my built app in Chrome using WebStorm's "Open in Browser" feature.

This morning however, the problem started. Every time I try to open up my project's index file in the browser, the page becomes unresponsive and eventually Chrome prompts me to kill the page. I cant even open developer tools.

Anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: This problem seems to be related to your code. Have you tried to remove your angular code to display only a HTML page ?

Comment: This is not really a question for stackoverflow; have you made any changes to the javascript ? Can you open it in another browser ? Any more debugging ?